# reshape and merge in stata

Tags: merge, stata, reshape

I have three data sets:

First, called education.dta. It contains individuals(students) over many years with their achieved educations from yr 1990-2000. Originally it is in wide format, but I can easily reshape it to long. It is presented as wide under:

id educ_90 educ_91 ... educ_00 cohort 
1    0       1           1       87
2    1       1           2       75
3    0       0           2       90

Second, called graduate.dta. It contains information of when individuals(students) have finished high school. However, this data set do not contain several years only a "snapshot" of the individ when they finish high school and characteristics of the individual students such as backgroung (for ex parents occupation).

id schoolid county cohort ...
1     11      123    87
2     11      123    75
3     22      243    90

The third data set is called teachers.dta. It contains informations about all teachers at high school such as their education, if they work full or part time, gender... This data set is long.

id schoolid  county  year    education
22    11       123    2011      1
21    11       123    2001      1 
23    22       243    2015      3

Now I want to merge these three data sets.

First, I want to merge education.dta and graduate.dta on id.
Problem when education.dta is wide: I manage to merge education and graduation.dta. Then I make a loop so that all the variables in graduation.dta takes the same over all years, for eksample:

forv j=1990/2000 {
gen county `j´=.
replace county`j´=county
}

However, afterwards when reshaping to long stata reposts that variable id does not uniquely identify the observations.

further, I have tried to first reshape education.dta to long, and thereafter merge either 1:m or m:1 with education as master, using graduation.dta.

However stata again reposts that id is not unique. How do I deal with this?

In next step I want to merge the above with teachers.dta on schoolid.

I want my final dataset in long format.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain that I have exactly the format of your data, it would be helpful if you gave us a toy dataset to look at using `dataex` (and could even help you figure out the problem yourself!)

But to start, because you are seeing that id is not unique, you need to figure out why there might be multiple ids in any of the datasets. Can someone in graduate.dta or education.dta appear more than once? `help duplicates` will probably be useful to explore the data in this way.

Because you want your dataset in long format I suggest reshaping education.dta to long first, then doing something like `merge m:1 id using "graduate.dta"` (once you figure out why some observations are showing up more than once) and then, finally something like `merge 1:1 schoolid year using "teacher.dta"` and you will have your final dataset.